# Highchart x-axis not printing date values

Tags: highcharts

I'm new to Highcharts and I have it working for most part as it prints the values to the y-axis nicely.

But I would also like to print out the timeline on the x-axis for the y-axis values like the date.

This I can't get to work, it's not printing out any y-axis date values.. I'm using it the wrong way.. can anyone point out my errors, here the config I'm using.. the "c.data.date" is what I'm trying to print out on the x-axis and there are the needed date values.

```
global: {
    useUTC: false
},
chart: {  
    renderTo: 'custom_report',  
    type: 'column',
    styleMode: true
},  
title: {
    text: 'Styling axes and columns'
},
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b', c.data.date);
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    name: "Ride Date",
    data: c.data.date
}],             
yAxis: [{
    className: 'highcharts-color-0',
        title: {
            text: "Duration / Length"
        }
}, 
{
    className: 'highcharts-color-1',
    opposite: true
}],

plotOptions: {
    column: {
        borderRadius: 5
    }
},
series: [{
    name: "Duration",
    data: c.data.duration
},{
    name: "Length",
    data: c.data.km
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working, replaced my x-axis with following code:

```
xAxis: [{
    categories: c.data.date,
    labels: {
        rotation: -45,
        style: {
            fontSize: '13px',
            fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
        }
    },
    crosshair: true
}],
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).